# Find all the solutions to the system of linear equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I was given this system of linear equations

$x + 2y = 1$

$2x + 4y = 2$

I basically put the system into matrix form and transformed it into rref.

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 4 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}

The rref matrix gives me the equation

$x + 2y = 1$, which then gives me $x = 1-2y$ and $y = \frac{1-x}{2}$

From here am I just plugging either x or y back into $x + 2y = 1$ (from the original system of equations)?

Also, the question asks to find the smallest and largest magnitude and I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: If $x+2y=1$, then automatically $2x+4y=2(x+2y)=2(1)=2$

Comment: Its asking me to find all the solutions. So is 2 all the solutions possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you got a row of zeroes means that your system is overdefined: the second equation is just double the first, so it's as if you just have $x+2y=1$.

Set $y=t$, where $t$ is some free variable that can take any value. Then $x=1-2y = 1-2t$, so the solutions will look like
$$(x,y) = (1-2t,t), \quad t \in \Bbb R$$

For the magnitude, we have $\left|(1-2t,t)\right| = \sqrt{(1-2t)^2+t^2}$, which is a function of $t$. This is clearly unbounded as $t\to\infty$; for the smallest value, you might find it easier to minimize the square of the magnitude, i.e.,
$$\min_t \sqrt{(1-2t)^2+t^2} = \min_t \left((1-2t)^2+t^2\right) = \ldots$$

Comment: Since y can essetially be any read number, how would I go about finding the largest and smallest magnitude among all solutions?

Comment: @AndyCohen See the edit.

Comment: Geometrically, do you see why there would be a unique minimum, but no maximum?

Comment: Yeah, essentially since t can be any real number, the magnitude can go on forever.

Comment: @AndyCohen True. You can also see it from a purely geometric point of view. The magnitude of $(x,y)$ is just the distance from the origin, so asking for the solution with the greatest or smallest magnitude really means finding a point on the line $x+2y=1$ that is farthest or closest to the origin. There is no farthest such point, because you can travel along the line as far you like, but there will be a unique closest such point.

Comment: How would I minimize the square of the magnitude to find the closest point?

Comment: @AndyCohen There are different ways to do that. Do you know any calculus?